# How to make event based flow run only once in a while

Tags: power-automate

I have made a flow that would trigger when a file is created in a folder (lets call it event folder). Based on that the flow would create another file in a different folder and send me a message that a new file has been created.

Now the event folder could have 1 or multiple files generated at once. My flow would trigger for each file created and spam me for all the files at once. I want only to have one message for any number of files created within the span of 5 minutes. Is there a way to do that?

Here is my flow
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `When a file is created (properties only)` block with Split On setting turned off and Concurrency Control turned on & Degree of parallelism set to 1 does the trick

See attached image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to store a 'new files created' status in some variable (possible hints at https://learn.microsoft.com/power-automate/create-variable-store-values ).

Then create some other flow, scheduled to run every 5 minutes (https://learn.microsoft.com/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks) to check the status, optionally send a message and clear the status to some 'nothing to do'.

Comment: I don't think I can use the variable block of one flow in another flow. I guess I have to create a temporary file and put some checks to make sure that only one is created and then I can use another flow to read that file and then delete it or something. Seems like it's gonna get needlessly complicated and the response could get too much delayed defeating the original purpose